# Live Preview mode Sanity on NextJS 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I cant seem to check if preview mode is activated or not for my website.

I was following a YouTube tutorial but I think it might be outdated when I am using the new NextJS update.

This is what i was required to do in order to check if preview mode was enabled or not.

```
import groq from 'groq';
import { previewData } from "next/headers"

const query = groq`
  *[_type=='post']{
    ...,
    author->,
    categories[]->,
  } | order(_createAt desc)`;

export default function Home() {
  if (previewData()) {
    return (
      <div><h1>In preview mode</h1></div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div><h1>Not in preview mode</h1></div>

  )
}
```

However it is noted that `next/headers` does not export `previewData()` anymore so I do not know what to do from here.

I have tried to use getServerSideProps however this is not able to be used on the app directory in NextJs 13.

Followed the tutorials on the Sanity documentation but it does not really solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after a few hours of finding the solution I have found it.

The documentation is here ([NextJs DraftMode](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers))

**Preview mode has been removed and replaced by DraftMode**

To check if your API is in DraftMode or not here is the code on the frontend

```
export default function Home() {
  const { isEnabled } = draftMode();
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>My Blog Post</h1>
      <p>Draft Mode is currently {isEnabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}</p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here are the API calls `app/api/draft/route.ts` & `app/api/exit-draft/route.ts` respectively.

```
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    draftMode().enable();
    return new Response('Draft mode is enabled');
}
```

To exit out of draftmode head to your /api/exit-draft.

```
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    draftMode().disable();
    return new Response('Draft mode is disabled');
}
```

Took awhile to solve this. In the end you need to set up your routes, cant direct it straight to the API call.