# previewData is not a function error after updating NextJS

Tags: next.js, sanity, next.js13, live-preview

I have a NextJS and Sanity.io blog project. Today I updated NextJS from 13.2.3 to 13.4.2 and when I try to run it, I get this error:

> Error: (0 , next_headers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.previewData) is
> not a function

Here's the code:

```
import { previewData } from "next/headers";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { client } from "../../lib/sanity.client";
import PreviewSuspense from "../../components/PreviewSuspense";
import BlogList from "../../components/BlogList";
import PreviewBlogList from "../../components/PreviewBlogList";

const query = groq`
    *[_type == "post"] {
        ...,
        author->,
        categories[]->
    } | order(_createdAt desc)
`;

//export const revalidate = 60; // revalidate this page every 60 seconds

export default async function HomePage() {
  if (previewData()) {
    return (
      <PreviewSuspense
        fallback={
          <div role="status">
            <p className="text-center text-lg animate-pulse text-[#F7AB0A]">
              Loading Preview Data...
            </p>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PreviewBlogList query={query} />
      </PreviewSuspense>
    );
  }

  const posts = await client.fetch(query);

  return <BlogList posts={posts} />;
}
```

How can I fix this? Do I have to use something else?

Comment: Are you using a `Head.js` somewhere?

Comment: No. I think the problem is with previewData from next/headers. Maybe it got deprecated, but I don't know what should I do then

Comment: So, I guess I have to use this new Draft Mode in nextjs instead of the previewData function, but right now I still don't know how I should rewrite the old code

Comment: Btw, I'm using next-sanity for the Live real-time preview mode

Comment: mybe this post, can help your problem
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202699/live-preview-mode-sanity-on-nextjs-13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202699/live-preview-mode-sanity-on-nextjs-13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case, i implements like this

in `app/api/draft/route.ts`

```
import { draftMode } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  draftMode().enable();
  redirect("/");
  // return new Response("Draft mode is enabled");
}
```

in `app/api/exit-draft/route.ts`

```
import { draftMode } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  draftMode().disable();
  redirect("/");
  // return new Response("Draft mode is disabled");
}
```

in `page.tsx`

```
import Content from "@/components/home/Content";
import { draftMode } from "next/headers";

export default function Home() {
  const { isEnabled } = draftMode();
  if (isEnabled) {
    return (
      <Content>
        <p>Draft Mode</p>
      </Content>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Content>
      <p>Homepage</p>
    </Content>
  );
}
```